# What is the difference between the AMQP protocol and CORE in ActiveMQ

Tags: java, amqp, activemq-artemis

I want to understand what is the difference between these protocols and where is it better to use which one

There is no normal explanation of these protocols in the official documentation

Comment: Any feedback here? Did my answer address your question?

Answer (score 0):

Both AMQP and core are *messaging* protocols.

AMQP is an [OASIS standard protocol](https://www.amqp.org/resources/download) which is supported by a number of different message brokers and has client implementations in many different languages across many different platforms. AMQP has broad industry support and is great for interoperability. It is 100% independent of ActiveMQ Artemis which is why the ActiveMQ Artemis documentation doesn't explain how it works. That kind information is available in the AMQP specification itself.

The core protocol supported by ActiveMQ Artemis is *only* supported by ActiveMQ Artemis and no other brokers. There are client implementations for both the JMS API and the core API. Both of these are in written in Java. There are no other client implementations.

Performance of both protocol implementations in the broker is roughly equivalent.

Generally speaking you'd probably want to use AMQP rather than core for interoperability and portability.